# how to sort the array list in HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, sorting

I'm having issues sorting out the ArrayList found inside of the hashmap, or treemap. the goal is to have the program print out the key, along with the sorted arraylist. I tried using Collections, but it didnt work, any help is welcome :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<StudentCourse> List = new ArrayList<StudentCourse>();

    List.add(new StudentCourse(2, "MATH210"));
    List.add(new StudentCourse(2, "CS105"));
    List.add(new StudentCourse(1, "S300"));
    List.add(new StudentCourse(1, "CS200"));

    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> HMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (StudentCourse st : List) {
        if (HMap.containsKey(st.getStudentID())) {
            HMap.get(st.getStudentID()).add(st.getCourse());
        } else {
            HMap.put(st.getStudentID(), new ArrayList<>());
            HMap.get(st.getStudentID()).add(st.getCourse());
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(List);//this leads to an error.



    Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> TrMap = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>(HMap);
    System.out.println(TrMap.toString());             
}
```

the output is this :
`{1=[S300, CS200], 2=[MATH210, CS105]}`

while the intent is to have the the arraylist sorted,
so:

`1=[cS200, S300],  2=[CS105, MATH210]`

Comment: I don't see any attempt at sorting.

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried which didn't work? Because there is really not much to it, just call `Collections.sort(list);` and it's sorted (create a [mcve]). Please stick to naming conventions, variable names should **always** start with lower case characters.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to specify a `Comparator` object or to define a **natural ordering** on your custom elements (by letting `StudentCourse` implement `Comparable`). Otherwise nobody knows how `StudentCourse` objects should be sorted.

Comment: @Zabuza It doesn't sound like OP's trying to sort a list of `StudentCourse`.

Comment: All you need to do is `map.values().forEach(Collections::sort);`

Comment: @shmosel, thats one of the main issues, in class we were never sorting strings found in arraylist, seen as values of a hashmap, so im lost on ways to sort accordingly. Sorting the keys accordingly wasnt an issue

Comment: What is the error/Stacktrace?

Comment: solution was found ! Thank you all for your help

Comment: You [can and should post your solution as a formal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it after the 48-hour delay, provided no better answers come along.

Comment: @BHustus thanks for the knowledge, didn't know if it was appropriate

Comment: Getting the program to sort out the Arraylist using :   `for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : TrMap.entrySet()) {
                Collections.sort(entry.getValue());        
            System.out.println(TrMap.toString());
            }`

Comment: That's a comment, the answer box should be down below. Large box with a blue button labeled "Post your answer".

Answer (score 1):

There is really not much to it. You just iterate all value entries and call some sort algorithm on it. For example the one provided by the `Collections#sort` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))) method. The method sorts inline so you don't have to re-add the values or anything, just call the method and your value entry will be sorted:

Probably the shortest code to realize this is

```
map.values().forEach(Collections::sort);
```

The `values` method returns a `Set` of all your values in the map. The `forEach` applies the given method to all entries.

---

If you are more familiar with regular loops:

```
for (ArrayList<String> value : map.values()) {
    Collections.sort(value);
}
```

The approach you have posted in your comments works too:

```
for (Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Collections.sort(entry.getValue());
}
```

but it is **unnecessary** to pull the whole `Entry` (with key) out of the map, you only need the values. So consider using the `map#values` method instead of the `map#entrySet`.